# my python console always gives me error when i try to import pandas

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdLlB.png)

> > > import pandas as pd
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: `pandas` is not a built-in module. Did you install it?

Comment: Have you installed pandas with the python version you are using? for example ```python3.7 -m pip install pandas```

Comment: If installed, pandas needs to be in your sys.path of python or python can't find it too.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install pandas!

Open your command prompt and type this:

```
pip install pandas
```

That should work!